# Can breezejs validate a newly created entity on property change NOT on SAVE

Tags: breeze

from the breezejs manual:"Breeze automatically validates entities in cache. It won’t do so for detached entities. For example, a newly created Customer is technically invalid because its CompanyName is null and that property is required. Breeze does not validate the customer until you add it to the cache. This gives you time to set the values of a new entity before it enters the cache and triggers validation."

My question is in the above context:

The samples floating in the web about breezejs and validation always show validation when a new entity is about to be created AND the SAVE button is pressed.

Can breezejs also validate property changes when I tab from one input field enter 100 chars  (10 are allowed) and tab to the next input field? I just want to show my validation error message on each property change NOT when the user hits the Save changes button.

Or does this not work for a new created entity as it is not yet added to the cache? Does that only work for entites edited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An entity is added to the cache by default. When you are creating an entity you can explicitly set its `entityState` to `Detached` or any other state if you would like. (`entityManager.createEntity('entityType', null, breeze.EntityState.Detached)`)

As for validation, you can manually validate entities in any state, at any time. If you want to check validation when a property is changed, simply subscribe to the `entityAspect.propertyChanged` event. The `propertyChanged` event will give you access to the entity itself, the name of the property that changed, the old value and the new value. Then you simply have to check the properties validation using `entity.entityAspect.validateProperty(propertyname)` and handle the results.

**Subscribe to property changes and validate manually**
(Code below is combined from breeze examples)

```
// assume order is an order entity attached to an EntityManager.
order.entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(
function (propertyChangedArgs) {
    // this code will be executed anytime a property value changes on the 'order' entity.
    var entity = propertyChangedArgs.entity; // Note: entity === order
    var propertyNameChanged = propertyChangedArgs.propertyName;
    var oldValue = propertyChangedArgs.oldValue;
    var newValue = propertyChangedArgs.newValue;

    if (!entity.entityAspect.validateProperty(propertyNameChanged)){
        //Property is not valid. Inform the user if needed.
    }

});
```

For more help and examples see these links's:
[Subscribing to the propertyChanged event](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#event_propertyChanged)
[Manually validating a property](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#method_validateProperty)
[Creating a new entity](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_createEntity)

Comment: Does all this property validation/subscibe also work when I have a Create Customer formular. I mean the customer entity does not exist yet so how can I do a propertyChanged.subscribe on it?

Comment: As soon as you call the createEntity function on the entityManager you have a full blown entity that you can subscribe and validate on. Everything is a "entity" regardless of its entityState or if it has been saved to the underlying database. When you are giving a user a form to create a record/entity you call `createEntity` then bind the returned entity to your view model.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is possible, you can do manual validation.

```
if (!newCustomer.entityAspect.validateEntity()) {/* do something about errors */}
You can also validate a specific property:

if (!newCustomer.entityAspect.validateProperty("CompanyName")) {
       /* do something about errors */}
```

I have get these examples from: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation

I hope this will help you.